# Using *arg and optional argument in one function

Tags: python, arguments

how can i use *arg and variables with defaull values together?

```
def my_fun(a, b = True, *arg):
    print (a)
    print (b)
    print (arg)

my_fun(1,2,3)
```

What I want to get is

```
1
True
(2,3,)
```

What I get is

```
1
2
(3)
```

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you catch all the args before the keyword arguments:

```
>>> def my_fun(*arg, a=1, b=2):
...     print (a)
...     print (b)
...     print (arg)
...
>>> my_fun(3,4,5)
1
2
(3, 4, 5)
```

And `a` and `b` can be modified by passing them as named parameters:

```
>>> my_fun(3,4,5, a=10, b=11)
10
11
(3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for doesn't make sense.

If I follow your logic, no matter how you call your function, `a` and `b` always will be `1` and `2`.

Comment: I made a mistake in question, I want to keep ability to change a and b variables

Comment: That was clear to me. Show an example where you call the function and `a` isn't `1`.

Comment: changed question, sry for mistakes in the beginning. I want to put optional arguements between "a" and "*arg". But dont understand how to let python define which value belongs to *arg and which to optional variable

Comment: That's what I'm telling you. You can't.